# How to delete the zero label on the axes when they are drawn in the center of the plot?

Tags: matplotlib, axes

I have a plot with the axes drawn crossing in the center. How can I remove the zeros at the place where they cross?

[image: example]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Riaky.png

Comment: Please add the code that generated the plot. Please also explain what you already tried.